# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context xcode 11

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11

i need help.
i tried to make an app that checks if number is prime. every time i try to run it it gives me the eror.
i am trying to add the text field in order to get an input.
allso could you help me get a better design? i was looking for colors to make it look daseling.
my code:

```
var number:Int = 56
var isPrime:Bool = true
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
var x = "is it prime?"
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var x = "is it prime?"


    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
                    Color.red
            HStack {
                TextField("Placeholder", text: number)
                Button(action: {switch number {

                    case 1:
                        isPrime = false

                    case 2:
                        isPrime = true

                    case 3:
                        isPrime = true

                    default:
                        primeCheck:for i in 2...Int(sqrt(Double(number))) {

                            if number % i == 0 {

                                isPrime = false
                                break primeCheck

                            }
                        }

                    }

                    if isPrime {

                        self.x = "The number \(number) is prime!"

                    } else {

                        self.x = "The number \(number) is composite!"
                    }}) {
                     Text("\(x)")
                    .frame(width:300,height:100)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .cornerRadius(40)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `@State` so that the UI updates based on the variable `x`

You should also move the variable inside the body since there is no need for the variable to be an instance variable.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var x = 1

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.x = 2
            }) {
                Text("increase")
            }
            Text("\(x)")
        }
    }
}
```